# Asking Chrome to bypass local cache for XmlHttpRequest like it's possible in Firefox?

Tags: ajax, caching, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

As some of you may already know, there are some caching issues in Firefox/Chrome for requests that are initiated by XmlHttpRequest object. These issues mean that browser does not strictly follow the rules and does not go to server for the new XSLT file (for example). Response does not have Expires header (for performance reasons we can't use it).

Firefox has additional parameter in the XHR object "channel" to which you put value Components.interfaces.nsIRequest.LOAD_BYPASS_CACHE to go to server explicitly.

Does something like that exist for Chrome?

**Let me immediatelly stop everyone** who would recommend adding timestamp as a value of GET parameter or random integer - I don't want server to get different URL requests. I want it to get the original URL. Reason is that I want to protect server from getting too many different requests for simple static files and sending too much data to clients when it is not needed.

If you hit static file with generated GET parameter (like '?forcenew=12314') would render 200 response each first time and 304 for every following request for that value of random integer. I want to make requests that will always return 304 if the target static file is identical to client version. This is BTW how web browsers should work out-of-the-box but XHR objects tend to not go to server at all to ask is file changed or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my main project at work I had the same exact problem. My solution was not to append random strings or timestamps to GET requests, but to append a **specific** string to GET requests.

If you have a revision number e.g. subversion revision or likewise from git/mer or whatever you are using, append that. Static files will get 304 responses until the moment a new revision is released. When the new release happens a single 200 response is granted and it is back to happily generating 304 responses. :-)

This has the added bonus of being browser independent.

Should you be unlucky and not have a revision number, then make one up and increment it each time you make a release.

Comment: I wanted to wait for the ending of this bounty to put the way how we solved it because I didn't want anyone to be influenced with our solution. We did exactly what you suggested :) In the moment we execute "republishing" of the web site we generate GET with timestamp of that moment. I really see no other way...

Comment: Good one with the timestamp - at work we have been discussing moving from subversion to git and I have been worrying about that git does not have a revision number. Perhaps we should go with timestamp too. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [Etags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag), etags are keys that can be generated from the contents of the file therefore once the file on the server changes the system will be a new etag.  Obviously this will be a service-side change which is something that you will need to do given that you want a 200 and then subsequent 304's.  Chrome and FF should respect these etags so you shouldn't need to do any crazy client-side hacks.

Comment: I understand your idea. We already have Etags sent to browser at this time. The problem is that Firefox/Chrome decide not to go to server in these cases at all when request is routed via XHR object. The question is how to make browser go to server in these cases (to bypass local browser cache).

Answer (score 0):

Chrome now supports `Cache-Control: max-age=0` request HTTP header. You can set it after you open an `XMLHttpRequest` instance:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader( "Cache-Control", "max-age=0" );
```

This will instruct Chrome to not use cached response without revalidation.

For more information check [The State of Browser Caching, Revisited](https://www.mnot.net/blog/2017/03/16/browser-caching) by Mark Nottingham and [RFC 7234 Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Caching](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2.1.1).

Comment: Just a FYI, incase of CORs requests, adding a header like the one above, will make a preflight OPTIONS call.